# Spacing of map scatter plot elements

Tags: graph, collision-detection, distance, matplotlib-basemap

I have a dense scatter plot on a map (produced using Python, matplotlib, and basemap). Here is a part of the image:

[image: Dense Scatter Plot]

I'd like to solve the overlap problem. I think the way to do this is to combine this simple lat/lon coordinate mapping with the technique I often see implemented in those "spring-loaded" network (social, not computer) graphs.

Is there a simple existing algorithm to auto-magically move these points so that they are not overlapping? If so, I can easily than add a small line from each point to its the correct lat/lon coordinate where it is currently located.

Note: Hexbin and heatmap is not a solution since the discrete values are important and should not be compromised.

Comment: *"the discrete values are important and should not be compromised"* -- that's exactly what you asked for if you want to move points around. The usual solution to points hiding others would be to use partially transparent points, not to tweak the data.

Comment: Moving points does not compromise their value, only their location, and this can be compensated for with lines showing where the dots belong. Transparency mean new colors, which means the colorbar becomes invalid.

Comment: The `matplotlib` `annotate` function comes to mind, but the issue remains how to do it systematically for all your points.

Comment: Nevermind, that function is for adding text with an arrow pointing to the data location. You want the data point itself moved from the given location and pointing back to that location.